# EXCEL VBA MACRO EDIT

Tags: excel, vba, dde

I need this macro to generate 2 (or more) data columns from 2 (or more) cell references.  Currently it only does one data series from one cell reference. The script generates a table and updates the table with a new data entry on each second, then updates a chart using the table data. The cell value is changing in real-time.

This should be a simple fix but I can't figure out the code. I'm out of my league. Any help would be awesome. Maybe somebody can refactor this or at least give me some hints as to what I should do.

```
Option Explicit
'Update the values between the quotes here:
Private Const sChartWSName = "Chart"
Private Const sSourceWSName = "Tickers"
Private Const sTableName = "tblValues"
Public RunTime As Double
Private Sub Chart_Setup()
'Create the structure needed to preserve and chart data
    Dim wsChart As Worksheet
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim shp As Button
    'Create sheet if necessary
    Set wsChart = Worksheets.Add
    wsChart.name = sChartWSName
    'Set up listobject to hold data
    With wsChart
        .Range("A1").value = "Time"
        .Range("B1").value = "Value"
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects.Add( _
                        SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                        Source:=.Range("A1:B1"), _
                        xllistobjecthasheaders:=xlYes)
        lstObject.name = sTableName
        .Range("A2").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        .columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 25
        .Select
    End With
    'Create the chart
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.AddChart.Select
        Set cht = ActiveChart
        With cht
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(sTableName)
            .PlotBy = xlColumns
            .Legend.Delete
            .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
            With .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .Weight = 1.25
            End With
        End With
    End With
    'Add buttons to start/stop the routine
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(242.25, 0, 83.75, 33.75)
    With shp
        .OnAction = "Chart_Initialize"
        .Characters.Text = "Restart Plotting"
    End With
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(326.25, 0, 83.75, 33.75)
    With shp
        .OnAction = "Chart_Stop"
        .Characters.Text = "Stop Plotting"
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub Chart_Initialize()
'Initialize the routine
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    'Make sure worksheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sChartWSName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call Chart_Setup
        Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sChartWSName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Check if chart data exists
    With Worksheets(sChartWSName)
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects(sTableName)
        If lstObject.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
            Select Case MsgBox("You already have data.  Do you want to clear it and start fresh?", vbYesNoCancel, "Clear out old data?")
                Case Is = vbYes
                    'User wants to clear the data
                    lstObject.DataBodyRange.Delete
                Case Is = vbCancel
                    'User cancelled so exit routine
                    Exit Sub
                Case Is = vbNo
                    'User just wants to append to existing table
            End Select
        End If
        'Begin appending
        Call Chart_AppendData
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Chart_AppendData()
'Append data to the chart table
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    Dim lRow As Long
    With Worksheets(sChartWSName)
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects(sTableName)
        If lstObject.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            lRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
        End If
        If lRow = 0 Then
            lRow = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).row
        End If
        .Range("A" & lRow).value = CDate(Now)
        .Range("B" & lRow).value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("M4").value
    End With
    RunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "Chart_AppendData"
End Sub
Public Sub Chart_Stop()
'Stop capturing data
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunTime, Procedure:="Chart_AppendData", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

This is the snippet from "ThisWorkbook"

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'Stop workbook refreshing
Call Chart_Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: do i understand correctly that you need to add more series in your chart (and table)? will the additional series based on the same x-axis?

Comment: I don't need two data series on the same chart.  The data just needs to be recorded in the table.  Two charts for the two data would be ideal, but this could be hard.  I can figure out how to chart the second series if it is just generated by the macro. Thanks for reading my problem!

Comment: then say you wanted to add a new column, you would do that in sub "Chart_AppendData()". After column A and B is set you could do ".Range("C" & lRow).value = your_value". However, you need to decide if you want this column to be part of the 'table' definition because the table definition (currently column A:B) is the chart data source.

Comment: When I add   .Range("C" & lRow).value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("M5").value            the chart stops working.  I don't know what to do.

Comment: when you go into the chart->"select data", how many data series do you have there?

Comment: Oh wow! I deleted the column and then restarted the macro and it started plotting both data series! Thanks a lot!  The only thing is that I really just want two charts one for each data.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: another chart, in another worksheet?

Comment: Well, yes I really need a chart for each data series.  It needs to be in the same workbook.

Comment: i guess you meant another worksheet, not another workbook

Comment: in any case, that seems to be a lot of work... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
    Option Explicit
'Update the values between the quotes here:
Private Const sChartWSName = "Chart"
Private Const sSourceWSName = "Tickers"
Private Const sTableName = "tblValues"
Public RunTime As Double
Private Sub Chart_Setup()
'Create the structure needed to preserve and chart data
    Dim wsChart As Worksheet
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim shp As Button
    'Create sheet if necessary
    Set wsChart = Worksheets.Add
    wsChart.Name = sChartWSName
    'Set up listobject to hold data
    With wsChart
        .Range("A1").Value = "Time"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Value1"
'**** I added C! and changed "Value" to "Value1" and "Value2"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Value2"
'**** I increased the range of the chart below to C1
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects.Add( _
                        SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                        Source:=.Range("A1:C1"), _
                        xllistobjecthasheaders:=xlYes)
        lstObject.Name = sTableName
        .Range("A2").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 25
        .Select
    End With
    'Create the chart
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.AddChart.Select
        Set cht = ActiveChart
        With cht
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(sTableName)
            .PlotBy = xlColumns
            .Legend.Delete
            .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
            With .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .Weight = 1.25
            End With
        End With
    End With
    'Add buttons to start/stop the routine
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(242.25, 0, 83.75, 33.75)
    With shp
        .OnAction = "Chart_Initialize"
        .Characters.Text = "Restart Plotting"
    End With
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(326.25, 0, 83.75, 33.75)
    With shp
        .OnAction = "Chart_Stop"
        .Characters.Text = "Stop Plotting"
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub Chart_Initialize()
'Initialize the routine
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    'Make sure worksheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sChartWSName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call Chart_Setup
        Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sChartWSName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Check if chart data exists
    With Worksheets(sChartWSName)
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects(sTableName)
        If lstObject.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
            Select Case MsgBox("You already have data.  Do you want to clear it and start fresh?", vbYesNoCancel, "Clear out old data?")
                Case Is = vbYes
                    'User wants to clear the data
                    lstObject.DataBodyRange.Delete
                Case Is = vbCancel
                    'User cancelled so exit routine
                    Exit Sub
                Case Is = vbNo
                    'User just wants to append to existing table
            End Select
        End If
        'Begin appending
        Call Chart_AppendData
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub Chart_AppendData()
'Append data to the chart table
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    Dim lRow As Long
    With Worksheets(sChartWSName)
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects(sTableName)
        If lstObject.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            lRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        End If
        If lRow = 0 Then
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        End If
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = CDate(Now)
        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = 4
        .Range("C" & lRow).Value = 5
'******I used the two line above to test results, uncomment the line below and feel free to change M5 to any other renge location workd best for you
'        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("M4").Value
'        .Range("C" & lRow).Value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("M5").Value
    End With
    RunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
   Application.OnTime RunTime, "Chart_AppendData"
End Sub
Public Sub Chart_Stop()
'Stop capturing data
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunTime, Procedure:="Chart_AppendData", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have exactly what I need with this solution.  You can just copy the chart that it generates, and then delete the first data series from the second chart.  They both update after that!  Thanks Jose, and thank you SNicolaou!